# Read wav file header - possibly with audacity - on linux

Tags: linux, audio, wav, audacity

On ubuntu linux, I want to be able to inspect a wav file such that I can read the wav header to determine the format. I have the tool audacity which, as an audio tool seems pretty good, but I can't find a way to see a decode of the wav header.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I don't know about Audacity but in python you may do it using [wav-file-header-information-using-python](http://blog.theroyweb.com/extracting-wav-file-header-information-using-a-python-script)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use ffmpeg on the terminal.
I think ffmpeg -i is what you are looking for.

example: `ffmpeg -i filename.wav`

When I do it on a random file i downloaded I get this feedback:

```
[jarco@geronimo ~]$ ffmpeg -i a-team_con_man.wav 
ffmpeg version 3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-avisynth --enable-avresample --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-shared --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : mono
Input #0, wav, from 'a-team_con_man.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:13.70, bitrate: 88 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_u8 ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 11025 Hz, 1 channels, u8, 88 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: Awesome dude, this works nicely +1 all around : )

Comment: `ffprobe filename.wav` produces a similar output, without the error.